# Bad syntax causing errors for MySQL query

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make some PHP that creates a query based on what it gets from the URL. I'm pretty sure I'm close to the code required to finish it but I can't get my syntax right. The idea is, it loops through all the companies in the URL ?companies=bla,bla,bla (which I stored in an array) and then for each one it echos part of the SQL statement for $query. **I know my code is going to be bad**. I am totally aware of that but I can't debug it without the right syntax. If someone could correct my syntax I'd highly appreciate it!

Thanks

```
$companies = $_GET['companies'];
$companiesArray = explode(',', $companies);
$companiesArrayLength = count($companiesArray);

$query = $db->query(
    for ($i = 0; $i < $companiesArrayLength; $i++) {
        echo "SELECT * FROM " . $companiesArray[$i] . " UNION ALL";
    }
    //echo " ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 50";
);
```

Comment: do you have a companies table, if yes, how does it look like?

Comment: You're **very** vulnerable towards SQL injection.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I am aware of that, I haven't added code to prevent it yet but I am aware of what needs to be done to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your last sub-query should not end with `UNION ALL`, can you do something like this:

```
$parts = array();

foreach ($companiesArray as $company)
    $parts[] = "SELECT * FROM " . $company;

$query = implode(" UNION ALL ", $parts) . " ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 50";
```

Answer (score 1):

So your code will end up being

```
SELECT * FROM a UNION ALL
...
SELECT * FROM k UNION ALL
```

and the final UNION ALL is not needed, that's why your are getting the error. Remove it so it looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM a UNION ALL
...
SELECT * FROM k
```

and it should execute. Make sure the column count in each table is the same too!

Comment: Thanks for this! It didn't fully answer my question as my PHP syntax was off but you certainly corrected my query! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't `echo` into a function-parameter (`query()` in this case). instead, build up a string and execute the whole query afterwards:

```
$querystring = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $companiesArrayLength; $i++) {
    $querystring .= "SELECT * FROM " . $companiesArray[$i];
    // no UNION ALL after the last part
    if($i != $companiesArrayLength-1){
        $querystring .= " UNION ALL";
    }
}
$querystring .= " ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 50";

$query = $db->query($querystring);
```

Comment: This answers my question perfectly, along with Andrius' query correction. Thanks very much.

Comment: you're welcome. please remember to mark the most helpful post as answer by clicking the tick-mark to the left of it when your question is solved.

Comment: Absolutely! I just have to wait for that timer :P

Comment: @jskidd3: I would prefer to use `foreach` and `implode`, it will result in cleaner code

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Only just seen your answer, sorry. Yours is the better one in my opinion so you win the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

$sqlQuery = NULL;

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $companiesArrayLength; $i++) {
  if ($i != $companiesArrayLength-1 ){
    $sqlQuery .= " SELECT * FROM " . $companiesArray[$i] . " UNION ALL ";
   } else {
    $sqlQuery .= " SELECT * FROM " . $companiesArray[$i] ;
   }
}

$sqlQuery .= " ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 50";
```

$query = $db->query($sqlQuery);

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do

```
foreach ($companiesArray as $company) {
    $sqls[] = "SELECT * FROM ".$company;
}
$sql = implode(" UNION ALL ", $sqls);
$query = $db->query($sql);
```

But, as you said, it's very dirty